# How to Let Percent Symbols (%) Read From a File Get Expanded in Windows Batch File?

Tags: batch-file

This is file `path.txt`:

```
%APPDATA%\foo
```

This is a part of batch file `read-path.bat`:

```
...
for /f %%i in (path.txt) do if not defined fooDir (
    if exist %%i (
        set "fooDir=%%i"
    ) else (
        >&2 echo ERROR: Invalid definition of fooDir: %%i
        pause
        popd
        exit /b 1
    )
)
...
```

When I run this batch file, it prompts that

```
ERROR: Invalid definition of fooDir: %APPDATA%\foo
```

How can I let it get parsed to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\foo`, instead of `%APPDATA%\foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code could be used:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%i in ("%~dp0path.txt") do if not defined fooDir (
    set "FolderPath=%%~i"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    call set "FolderPath=!FolderPath!"
    for %%j in ("!FolderPath!\") do (
        endlocal
        if exist "%%~fj" (
            set "fooDir=%%~fj"
        ) else (
            endlocal
            >&2 echo ERROR: Invalid definition of fooDir: %%j
            pause
            exit /B 1
        )
    )
)
set foodir
endlocal
```

That code works for following folder paths in `path.txt` in directory of the batch file:

```
%APPDATA%\foo
%APPDATA%\Development & Test()!
%APPDATA%\..\Roaming\Development & Test()!\\\
```

But it does not work for:

```
%APPDATA%\Development % Test()!
```

So if the folder path contains additionally to zero or more environment variable references also a percent sign which should be interpreted literally as being part of a folder name, the code does not work.

The command **CALL** left to `set "FolderPath=!FolderPath!"` results in interpreting the percent signs in folder path read from the file and expanding the environment variable references, but also in removing a single percent sign which should be interpreted as literal character and not as start/end of an environment variable reference. There should not found by `cmd.exe` a file with name `set` in current directory or a directory listed in environment variable `PATH` having a file extension listed in environment variable `PATHEXT` as in this case this executable or script would be called instead of executing internal command **SET**.

The inner **FOR** is used to get the real absolute folder path always ending with a single backslash on folder path read from file contains relative path parts as well according to the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

**Note:** The environment variable `foodir` is defined always with a backslash at end.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`